# Alternative route app

Tags: ios, maps, external-application

Maps has an option for choosing an external app, as you can see in the picture below. Is it possible to do the same with a third-party app? I mean I would like to add this feature in my app.

[image]

Comment: You mean you want a list of apps from the store that support 3rd party routing?

Comment: Yes, and also opening the chosen one.